# Laravel Class Swift_Mailer not found

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-4

I'm trying to send an email using laravel 4.2.1 + gmail but I'm getting the following error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Swift_Mailer' not found
```

Here is my mail config file

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => 'mygmail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Admin'),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'mygmail@gmail.com',
'password' => 'mypassword',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Here the code that sends the email

```
 $data = [
            'activationLink'=>$activationCode
        ];    
Mail::send('emails.register.activation', $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->to('email@outlook.com')
                    ->subject('Activate Your Account');
        });
```

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: What username and password are you using…?

Comment: my gmail username and password. I can't post that in here that's why I put a placeholder for the username and password

Comment: Congratulations. You passed the test ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have these lines in your autoload.php

```
 // Swiftmailer needs a special autoloader to allow
 // the lazy loading of the init file (which is expensive)
 require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php';
 Swift::registerAutoload(__DIR__.'/../vendor/swiftmailer/lib/swift_init.php');
```

Comment: Thank you man. you got me to the right direction. I went to vendor/sswiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/ and for some reason the folder Swift was renamed to Swift (1) I changed the name and all is good ;)